# Normalizing using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

There is this sample record,
100,1:2:3

Which I want to normalize as,
100,1
100,2
100,3

A colleague of mine wrote a pig script to achieve this and my MapReduce code took more time. I was using the default TextInputformat before. But to improve performance, I decided to write a custom Input format class, with a custom RecordReader. Taking the LineRecordReader class as reference, I tried to write the following code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader;

import com.normalize.util.Splitter;

public class NormalRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, Text> {

    private long start;
    private long pos;
    private long end;
    private LineReader in;
    private int maxLineLength;
    private Text key = null;
    private Text value = null;
    private Text line = null;

    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        this.maxLineLength = job.getInt("mapred.linerecordreader.maxlength", Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();

        final Path file = split.getPath();

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());

        in = new LineReader(fileIn, job);
        this.pos = start;
    }

    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        int newSize = 0;
        if (line == null) {
            line = new Text();
        }

        while (pos < end) {
            newSize = in.readLine(line);
            if (newSize == 0) {
                break;
            }
            pos += newSize;
            if (newSize < maxLineLength) {
                break;
            }

            // line too long. try again
            System.out.println("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " + (pos - newSize));
        }
        Splitter splitter = new Splitter(line.toString(), ",");
        List<String> split = splitter.split();

        if (key == null) {
            key = new Text();
        }
        key.set(split.get(0));

        if (value == null) {
            value = new Text();
        }
        value.set(split.get(1));

        if (newSize == 0) {
            key = null;
            value = null;
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the progress within the split
     */
    public float getProgress() {
        if (start == end) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else {
            return Math.min(1.0f, (pos - start) / (float)(end - start));
        }
    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Though this works, but I haven't seen any performance improvement. Here I am breaking the record at "," and setting the 100 as key and 1,2,3 as value. I only call the mapper which does the following:

```
public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    try {
        Splitter splitter = new Splitter(value.toString(), ":");
        List<String> splits = splitter.split();

        for (String split : splits) {
            context.write(key, new Text(split));
        }

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ibe) {
        System.err.println(value + " is malformed.");
    }
}
```

The splitter class is used to split the data, as I found String's splitter to be slower. The method is:

```
public List<String> split() {

    List<String> splitData = new ArrayList<String>();
    int beginIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;

    while(true) {

        endIndex = dataToSplit.indexOf(delim, beginIndex);
        if(endIndex == -1) {
            splitData.add(dataToSplit.substring(beginIndex));
            break;
        }

        splitData.add(dataToSplit.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
        beginIndex = endIndex + delimLength;
    }

    return splitData;
}
```

Can the code be improved in any way?

Comment: What is the order of performance difference compared to the pig script?

Comment: The Pig Scrip runs in ~50 secs and the MapReduce in ~1 min. But I was hoping for performance at least be as good as the pig script if not better.

Comment: IMO that's too short for a performance comparison for map reduce. It's hard to say if that difference is significant. If you really want to find out, I'd recommend testing at volume that takes something like 20 - 60 minutes.

Comment: I have already testing using ~15 GB file. Can you look at the code though and see if it can be optimized.

Comment: Did you compile a pattern with "," or did you use `String#.split(",")`. The last is going to compile a pattern each time split is called and thus slower.

Comment: You're creating a `Text` object several times per record, you should define 1 instance variable initialized in the `setup` method and then call `.set` in your `map`, which will avoid a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut I did not use String split, but instead wrote my own custom method which I've posted above. It uses the string indexOf and substring methods.

Comment: @Charles Menguy I'll try that and let you know. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Charles Menguy I just changed the map code such that it does not create a new Text object every time. It did bring down the time by a few seconds, but the pig script still runs faster. Is there any other optimization that I can carry out?

Comment: I added some more ideas as an answer as it wouldn't fit in a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize here what I think you can improve instead of in the comments:

- As explained, currently you are creating a `Text` object several times per record (number of times will be equal to your number of tokens). While it may not matter too much for small input, this can be a big deal for decently sized jobs. To fix that, do the following:

  ```
  private final Text text = new Text();

  public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
      ....
      for (String split : splits) {
          text.set(split);
          context.write(key, text);
      }
  }
  ```
- For your splitting, what you're doing right now is for every record allocating a new array, populating this array, and then iterating over this array to write your output. Effectively you don't really need an array in this case since you're not maintaining any state. Using the implementation of the `split` method you provided, you only need to make one pass on the data:

  ```
  public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
      String dataToSplit = value.toString();
      String delim = ":";

      int beginIndex = 0;
      int endIndex = 0;

      while(true) {
          endIndex = dataToSplit.indexOf(delim, beginIndex);
          if(endIndex == -1) {
              text.set(dataToSplit.substring(beginIndex));
              context.write(key, text);
              break;
          }

          text.set(dataToSplit.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
          context.write(key, text);
          beginIndex = endIndex + delim.length();
      }
  }
  ```
- I don't really see why you write your own `InputFormat`, it seems that `KeyValueTextInputFormat` is exactly what you need and has probably been already optimized. Here is how you use it:

  ```
  conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");
  job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
  ```
- Based on your example, the key for each record seems to be an integer. If that's always the case, then using a `Text` as your mapper input key is not optimal and it should be an `IntWritable` or maybe even a `ByteWritable` depending on what's in your data.
- Similarly, you want want to use an `IntWritable` or `ByteWritable` as your mapper output key and output value.

Also, if you want some meaningful benchmark, you should test on a bigger dataset, like a few Gbs if possible. 1 minute tests are not really meaningful, especially in the context of distributed systems. 1 job may run quicker than another one on a small input, but the trend may be reverted for bigger inputs.

That being said, you should also know that Pig does a lot of optimizations behind the hood when translating to Map/Reduce, so I'm not too surprised that it runs faster than your Java Map/Reduce code and I've seen that in the past. Try the optimizations I suggested, if it's still not fast enough here is [a link on profiling your Map/Reduce jobs](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/) with a few more useful tricks (especially tip 7 on profiling is something I've found useful).

Comment: I tried the optimizations you posted. I don't know why it never struck me that I was making two passes over the data. But unfortunately, I didn't see any changes in the processing time. FYI, I haven't used the any integer related classes because I have reasons to believe the actual data I'll be processing will contain text. Now I'll be trying the optimizations provided in the link you gave. As always, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Just a question, I always thought that marking a variable "final" made it a constant. If that's not the case, what does it do?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore A final variable can only be initialized once, the reference cannot be changed, however the content of the object can be modified like here.

Comment: So this means that even if I create an object as "public static final", it's reference is not changed but its value can be? So is there no way to describe a true constant in Java?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore You're right, `final` means you cannot change the reference but, if the object is **mutable** like `Text` then you can still change is content. To achieve "true constants" you would need to do that for an **immutable** object, for example Strings, a final String cannot be modified since String is immutable.

Comment: So I ran the MR code for an all text input and viola, MR finished the processing in half the time taken by Pig. Looks like Pig has some in-built optimizations which reads the key-value pairs as integers if the input is so. So I tried to modify my MR code to read the key as an Integer and the value as a Text. But I can't seem to get it working. I am getting the `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable` at the line where the map method is defined, though I am pretty sure I've checked everywhere.

Comment: This seems to work very well for Text based inputs. So I'll accept the answer.